# Test the hypothesis whether the passing percentage of this year is significant lower than 0.5 in R?

Tags: r, estimation

I have a vector that contains the grades of this year. And I need to test hypothesis using a 1% significance level and using the p-value.

I tried something like this:

```
t.test(length(x[x >= 6])/length(x), mu = 0.5, alternative = "less" )
```

But this gives the error: not enough 'x' observations, I understand this error but I have no idea to solve this differently.

Comment: you are doing a t.test on n=1 which doesn't make sense, see if the answer posted is what you need

Comment: can you explain what is the null hypothesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that you are not testing the right argument. `length(x[x >= 6])/length(x)` is a scalar: you are therefore testing if a number is equal to 0.5, which does not make sense. To use a Student's t test you have to give a vector as input.

If I understand your objective correctly, you seem to want to test if the proportion of grades above 6 is significantly different from 50%. So you don't need a Student's t test, but rather a binomial test. In fact you want to count how many grades are higher than 6 compared to the total number of grades (*n*). If this is what you are looking for, the following code should allow you to answer your problem.

```
prop.test(x = length(x[x>6]), n= length(x), alternative = "less")
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, not so sure what OP is trying to test. Might want to add in your code, that the null hypothesis is that the proportion (of grades > 6 ) is 0.5

Comment: When I used `prop.test()` the probability under the null hypothesis was precisely 50% by default. Unfortunately this proportion can't be changed with this function but I have seen other R functions that can perform the same kind of test and they certainly have the opportunity to integrate another probability under the null hypothesis if needed.

Comment: well... you can do `prop.test(..., p = 0.3)` for example

Comment: My bad, I have read the documentation a bit quickly, indeed the argument p solves the problem